# Nested expression in a UNIX shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, expect

I have a script to download files using scp and then save files by appending current date.

I got error message:

```
local_computer:~ memo$ ./scp_auto_save.sh 
can't read "(date +%d-%m-%y)": no such variable
while executing
"spawn scp "root@ch1.local:/root/*.csv" ./ch1_$(date +%d-%m-%y).csv"
(file "./scp_auto_save.sh" line 4)
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# connect via scp - ch1
spawn scp "root@ch1.local:/root/*.csv" ./ch1_$(date +%d-%m-%y).csv
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "password\r" 
    } 
}
interact
```

Q1:
How to correctly express $(date +%d-%m-%y) inline with the scp command?

Q2:
I have many files stored in 20 remote machines. How to scp each machine?

For example:

```
spawn scp "root@ch1.local:/root/*.csv" ./ch1_current_date.csv
spawn scp "root@ch2.local:/root/*.csv" ./ch2_current_date.csv
:
:
spawn scp "root@ch20.local:/root/*.csv" ./ch20_current_date.csv
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `expect` is not a shell. It doesn't evaluate shell expressions/variables/etc. You can generate that date in tcl or (probably) pass it in as an argument.

Comment: To exec for your 20 remote machine, look at [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command

Comment: Thanks guys! Learn from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```tcl
set date [timestamp %Y-%m-%d]   ; # this is an expect-specific command
set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y-%m-%d]   ; # this works too

set hosts {
    ch1.local
    ch2.local
    ...
}

foreach host $hosts {
    spawn scp "root@$host:/root/*.csv" ./${host}_$date.csv
    expect {
        -re ".*es.*o.*" {
            exp_send "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        -re ".*sword.*" {
            exp_send "password\r" 
        } 
    }
    expect eof
}
```